Display normalized decimal (18 digit) or native decimal of ERC20
I am building a pool which allow user to buy and sell 2 ERC20 token. When calculate the number, token decimal will be normalized into 18 decimal. So should my view function expose normalized decimal of both token or native decimal of both

It depends on your target audience and how you expect them to interact with the pool. If your users are mostly developers or advanced users who are comfortable with token decimals, exposing the native decimals might be more straightforward. However, if you want to make the experience more consistent and user-friendly, especially for a broader audience, normalizing to 18 decimals could be beneficial.
You could also consider providing both options:

A view function that exposes the amounts in normalized decimals for consistency.

Another view function that shows the native decimals for users who prefer the actual token representations.


This way, users can choose the format that best suits their needs.
